# Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor() Transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement transfer learning on my own model but failing. My implementation follows the guides here

https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/

[How to do transfer-learning on our own models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336761/how-to-do-transfer-learning-on-our-own-models/51337328)

https://github.com/anujshah1003/Transfer-Learning-in-keras---custom-data/blob/master/transfer_learning_resnet50_custom_data.py

`tensoflow 2.4.1`
`Keras 2.4.3`

Old Model (Works really well):

```
model = Sequential()
inputShape = (256, 256, 3)
chanDim = -1
  
# CONV => RELU => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Transfer Learning:

```
old_model = load_model('old.model')

# removes top 2 activation layers
for i in range(2):
  old_model.pop()

# mark loaded layers as not trainable
for layer in old_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# initialize the new model

in_puts = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
count = len(old_model.layers)
ll = old_model.layers[count - 1].output
classes = len(lb.classes_)
ll = Dense(classes)(ll)
ll = Activation("softmax", name="activation3_" + NODE)(ll)
model = Model(inputs=in_puts, outputs=ll) # ERROR

opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
H = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)


# save the model to disk
model.save("new.model")
```

**ERROR**

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32,
name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'") at
layer "conv2d". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple way to operate transfer learning with your model

```
classes = 10
sub_old_model = Model(old_model.input, old_model.layers[-3].output)
sub_old_model.trainable = False

ll = Dense(classes)(sub_old_model.output)
ll = Activation("softmax")(ll)

model = Model(inputs=sub_old_model.input, outputs=ll)
```

Firstly, create a sub-model with layers from the old model that you want to freeze (`trainable = False`). In our example, we take all the layers excluding the last `Dense` and the `Softmax` activation.

Then pass the sub-model output into the new trainable layers.

At this point, you simply need to create a new model instance to assemble all the pieces

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Marco Cerliani, I was able to solve the problem by changing to `LabelEncoder` and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: hi, I created a custom model. now I have one more dataset. So my goal is to do transfer learning and update the model.  After following many links and videos, I still not get the desire model.  `loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00` this is what I am getting. Can you help me with the steps.