# Tensorflow CNN transfer learning has constant low validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

Hello I have been trying to create two tensorflow models to experiment with transfer learning. I have a trainned a cnn model for lung xray images for pneumonia(2 classes) by using the [kaggle chest x-ray dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia) .

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras

import os

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data = gen.flow_from_directory("/Users/saibalaji/Downloads/chest_xray/train",target_size=(500,500),batch_size=32,class_mode='binary')

test_data = gen.flow_from_directory("/Users/saibalaji/Downloads/chest_xray/test",target_size=(500,500),batch_size=32,class_mode='binary')


model = keras.Sequential()


# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 1

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(500,500,3)))

model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))


# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 2

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))


# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 3

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))


# Convolutional layer and maxpool layer 4

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))


# This layer flattens the resulting image array to 1D array

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())


# Hidden layer with 512 neurons and Rectified Linear Unit activation function

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))


# Output layer with single neuron which gives 0 for Cat or 1 for Dog

#Here we use sigmoid activation function which makes our model output to lie between 0 and 1
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

hist = model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_data,
steps_per_epoch = 163,
epochs = 4,
validation_data = test_data
)
```

I have saved the model in .h5 format.

Then I created a new notebook loaded data from kaggle for [alzheimer's disease](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tourist55/alzheimers-dataset-4-class-of-images) and loaded my saved pneumonia model. Copied its layer to a new model except last layer then Freezed all the layers in the new model as non trainable. Then added a output dense layer with 4 neurons for 4 classes. Then trainned only the last layer for 5 epochs. But the problem is val accuaracy remains at 35% constant. How can I improve it.

Here is my code for alzeihmers model

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

traindata = datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/saibalaji/Documents/TensorFlowProjects/ad/train',target_size=(500,500),batch_size=32)

testdata = datagen.flow_from_directory('/Users/saibalaji/Documents/TensorFlowProjects/ad/test',target_size=(500,500),batch_size=32)

model = keras.models.load_model('pn.h5')

nmodel = keras.models.Sequential()

#add all layers except last one

for layer in model.layers[0:-1]:

nmodel.add(layer)

for layer in nmodel.layers:

layer.trainable = False

nmodel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=4,name='dense_last'))

hist = nmodel.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.002),loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

nmodel.fit(x=traindata,validation_data=testdata,epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=160)
```

Here is my prediction code.

```
 class_labels = []
    for class_label,class_mode in traindata.class_indices.items():
        print(class_label)
        class_labels.append(class_label)
    def predictimage(filepath):
        test_image = image.load_img(path=filepath,target_size=(500,500))
        image_array = image.img_to_array(test_image)
        image_array = image_array / 255
        print(image_array.shape)
        image_array_exp = np.expand_dims(image_array,axis=0)
        result = nmodel.predict(image_array_exp)
        print(result)
        plt.imshow(test_image)
        plt.xlabel(class_labels[np.argmax(result)])
```

I also noticed that it is predicting only two classes even though I have changed the last layer to 4 neurons, changed the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't add an activation function in your last layer.
Maybe it would be helpful to use the `softmax` activation function.

```py
nmodel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation= "softmax", name='dense_last'))
```

Comment: Thanks I have added it and retrained  the last layer. But I have also noticed that the model still classifies only two classes even though I have changed the last layer to 4 neurons with activation function and trained it. I have updated my code with a prediction function. Idk where I'm going wrong

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to use MobileNet model. Changed its last layer and It gave me around 60% val accuracy. And it somewhat classifies all 4 classes. How can I do it with my own cnn model instead of using a Mobilenet so that it classifies all 4 classes.

Comment: Do you mean your output is just one probability ?! Did you print `nmodel.summary()` to see if everything is ok with architecture?

Comment: Yes have tried nmodel.summary() architecture is fine with last layer having 4 neurons and softmax activation function. When I print the prediction result I get an array of 4 elements as expected. But only second and third elements are positive and other two are negative values. I think my model is classifying only two classes even though I trained the output layer with 4 neurons. And the accuracy is pretty bad only 35%. I can't find any tutorial which uses two seperate CNN models created from scratch. Instead all of them uses Mobilenet or vgg for tensorflow transfer learning

Comment: It's very strange because `softmax` always outputs positive values. If you're getting negative values, probably something is wrong with the implementation. Unfortunately, I'm more familiar with PyTorch, but I will tell you if I figure it out. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336761/how-to-do-transfer-learning-on-our-own-models) too. There is some information about using transfer learning with your model.